# SQL unit test on SP

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, stored-procedures, visual-studio-2017

I've been working on an SQL unit test on VS 2017. I want to use local repo for all my tests.
Whenever I try to run the test cases I face an error

> Failed to deploy database project

I tried multiple fixes but in vain.

Comment: Please add the detailed error of visual studio

Comment: We love that you're here and we really cannot help you based on what you've provided.

Comment: Please add more information.  This is way too little to assist.

Comment: Thank you everyone for lending a hand in support. I have figured out the problem. 
I created a new local instance for deployment and it's working absolutely fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for lending a hand in support. I have figured out the problem.
I created a new local instance for deployment and it's working absolutely fine now.